# Salesforce Inbox on Salesforce SDK

Tags: push-notification, salesforcesdk, inbox

First of all this action is sent from Push Notification module on Salesforce Dashboard.
Second we are using Salesforce SDK for integration to mobile app (Android and iOS).
Here is the queries :

1. How to make the message inbox saved on Salesforce server instead saved locally on mobile device? We need this to make each of our customer had their own Inbox on any device, instead of only appearing on that device.
2. We need to add 1 more field / custom field (ex. Tag / Category) that we can use to differentiate the message. We already checked the response from push notification and inbox message is different, and and we cannot / don't know which field can be used for this